# Updating document with url overwrites all urls in existing documents

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have code in my Recyclerview Adapter that:

1. When a tag containing a string clicked `onTagClick`, uploads `uploadFiles(...)` a file then returns a URL.
2. When the URL is captured on `addOnCompleteListener`, `updateAnswer(...)` updates an object `position` inside the document. `answer` is the object field that is updated with the url.

The issue here is that all documents get updated with the same get the `answer` field updated with the same url. I have tried to find a fix but cannot seem to be able to solve it.

```
public class AdapterNewDetails extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterNewDetails.MyViewHolder> {
    CustomClasses customclasses;
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    FirebaseFirestore db;

    private List<GnCCompletedDetails> feedItems;
    Boolean uploading = false;
    private Context mContext;
    String thecurentdocid = "";

    public AdapterNewDetails(Context paramContext, List<GnCCompletedDetails> paramList) {
        this.mContext = paramContext;
        this.feedItems = paramList;
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.feedItems.size();
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder paramMyViewHolder, int paramInt) {
        String str;
        GnCCompletedDetails gnCCompletedDetails = this.feedItems.get(paramInt);
        TextView textView = paramMyViewHolder.question;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(gnCCompletedDetails.getPosition().toString());
        stringBuilder.append(". ");
        stringBuilder.append(gnCCompletedDetails.getQuestion().toString());
        textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());

        if (gnCCompletedDetails.getType().equals("radio")) {
            str = gnCCompletedDetails.getAnswer().toString();
            paramMyViewHolder.answer.setText(str);
            paramMyViewHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            paramMyViewHolder.filesrray.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (gnCCompletedDetails.getType().equals("dropdown")) {
            str = gnCCompletedDetails.getAnswer().toString();
            paramMyViewHolder.answer.setText(str);
            paramMyViewHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            paramMyViewHolder.filesrray.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (gnCCompletedDetails.getType().equals("text")) {
            str = gnCCompletedDetails.getAnswer().toString();
            paramMyViewHolder.answer.setText(str);
            paramMyViewHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            paramMyViewHolder.filesrray.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (gnCCompletedDetails.getType().equals("gps")) {
            try {
                JSONObject gpsobj = new JSONObject(gnCCompletedDetails.getAnswer().toString());
                String one = "Latitude: " + gpsobj.get("lat").toString();
                String two = "<br><br>Longitude: " + gpsobj.get("long").toString();
                paramMyViewHolder.answer.setText(Html.fromHtml(one + two));
                paramMyViewHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                paramMyViewHolder.filesrray.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } else if (gnCCompletedDetails.getType().equals("checkbox")) {
            str = gnCCompletedDetails.getAnswer().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
            paramMyViewHolder.answer.setText(str);
            paramMyViewHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            paramMyViewHolder.filesrray.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (gnCCompletedDetails.getType().equals("multi_text")) {
            str = gnCCompletedDetails.getAnswer().toString();
            this.customclasses.parseMultitestAns(str, paramMyViewHolder.answer);
            paramMyViewHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            paramMyViewHolder.filesrray.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (gnCCompletedDetails.getType().equals("file_upload")) {
            str = gnCCompletedDetails.getAnswer().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
            paramMyViewHolder.answer.setText(str);
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList((Object[]) str.split(",")));
            paramMyViewHolder.answer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            paramMyViewHolder.filesrray.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            paramMyViewHolder.filesrray.setTags(arrayList);
            paramMyViewHolder.filesrray.setOnTagClickListener(new TagView.OnTagClickListener() {
                public void onSelectedTagDrag(int param1Int, String param1String) {
                }

                public void onTagClick(int param1Int, String param1String) {
                    if (param1String.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith("http")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(param1String.trim()));
                        AdapterNewDetails.this.mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        if (!uploading) {
                            uploadFiles(param1String, gnCCompletedDetails.getPosition().toString(), arrayList, gnCCompletedDetails);
                            Toasty.info(mContext, "Uploading image, please wait.", Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            thecurentdocid = gnCCompletedDetails.getDocid().toString();
                            Log.d("TAG", "uploadFiles: " + gnCCompletedDetails.getDocid().toString());
                        } else {
                            Toasty.info(mContext, "File upload already in progress, please wait until it's completed.", Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                }

                public void onTagCrossClick(int param1Int) {
                }

                public void onTagLongClick(int param1Int, String param1String) {
                }
            });
        }
        paramMyViewHolder.cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View param1View) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void uploadFiles(String param1String, String position, ArrayList arrayList, GnCCompletedDetails item) {
        uploading = true;
        Log.d("TAG", "uploadFiles: " + param1String);

        File file = new File(URI.create(param1String.trim()).getPath());
        if (file.exists()) {

            StorageReference ref = storage.getReference("insight/surveyimages/");
            ref.child(UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg");

            ref.putFile(Uri.parse(param1String.trim())).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                public Task<Uri> then(Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> param1Task) throws Exception {
                    if (param1Task.isSuccessful()) {
                        return ref.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                    throw param1Task.getException();

                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                public void onComplete(Task<Uri> param1Task) {
                    if (param1Task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri uri = param1Task.getResult();
                        int thepos = arrayList.indexOf(param1String);
                        arrayList.set(thepos, uri.toString());

                        updateAnswer(arrayList, position, item);

                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toasty.warning(mContext, "File does not exist", Toasty.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void updateAnswer(ArrayList arrayList, String position, GnCCompletedDetails item) {
        Log.d("TAG", "updateAnswer: " + item.getDocid() + " Position " + position);
        if (thecurentdocid.equals(item.getDocid())) {
            JSONObject joyce = new JSONObject();
            try {
                joyce.put("answer", arrayList.toString());
                joyce.put("question", item.getQuestion().toString());
                joyce.put("position", item.getPosition().toString());
                joyce.put("type", item.getType().toString());
                Map<String, Object> map = toMap(joyce);

                if (customclasses.demo()) {
                    DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("insight").document("data").collection("survey_responses_demo").document(item.getDocid().toString());
                    documentReference.update(position, map).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                            uploading = false;

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("insight").document("data").collection("survey_responses").document(item.getDocid().toString());
                    documentReference.update(position, map).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            uploading = false;

                        }
                    });
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup paramViewGroup, int paramInt) {
        this.customclasses = new CustomClasses();
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(paramViewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.holder_completed_view_answers, paramViewGroup, false));
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView answer;

        CardView cardview;

        TagContainerLayout filesrray;

        public TextView question;

        public MyViewHolder(View param1View) {
            super(param1View);
            this.cardview = (CardView) param1View.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
            this.question = (TextView) param1View.findViewById(R.id.question);
            this.answer = (TextView) param1View.findViewById(R.id.answer);
            this.filesrray = (TagContainerLayout) param1View.findViewById(R.id.filesrray);
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject jsonobj) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Iterator<String> keys = jsonobj.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            Object value = jsonobj.get(key);
            if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static List<Object> toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Object value = array.get(i);
            if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            } else if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            list.add(value);
        }
        return list;
    }


}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 250 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: The extra lines are for context, the relevant code is highlighted in the description, please refer to it.